# Tomcat and Jetty only work once in Windows and then crash

Tags: windows, spring-mvc, tomcat, jetty, spark-java

I've had a series of issues with both SparkJava and SpringMVC's embedded servers in my Windows 7 installation. These two web frameworks use Jetty and Tomcat respectively as embedded web servers. Building and running both for the first time is successful. `127.0.0.1:<port>` is listened to by the server, accessed and everything works as expected.

However, when it comes the time to terminate the process in command line, using `Ctrl + C`, the servers no longer work no matter what I do. In both instances, the servers crash either after a request from localhost, or five minutes of inactvity in both, the error message is as follows:

```
2016-04-03 12:56:54.604 ERROR 6360 --- [main] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol: Failed to start end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]

java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:101) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:68) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl.<init>(PipeImpl.java:170) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openPipe(SelectorProviderImpl.java:50) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at java.nio.channels.Pipe.open(Pipe.java:155) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.<init>(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:127) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorProvider.openSelector(WindowsSelectorProvider.java:44) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at java.nio.channels.Selector.open(Selector.java:227) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
```

This is the Spring MVC output, but SparkJava has an almost identical output. I have tried the following:

- Check with netstat if there are any other processes hogging the ports.
- Close down my IDE in case there are some build files it wants to hold onto
- Run `mvn clean` before every compile
- Run SpringMVC as a jar file.

In my Ubuntu installation, both of these embedded run smoothly, and I am able to terminate both processes and start them again without any hassle. So, this is exclusively a Windows problem.

I came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26310297/java-io-ioexception-unable-to-establish-loopback-connection-java-net-bindexcept) that posited a similar issue, but running the test tool did not throw any exception.

Comment: It feels like your ^C method isn't actually shutting down the server.  Did you try what this guy suggests to debug the ports?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15651644/jetty-server-not-starting-unable-to-establish-loopback-connection

Comment: Bob Kuhar I ran the port debugger. No issues. apart from some minor differences, the output of the port debugger is identical. Netstat also doesn't report the ports I use for the embedded server to be in use when the server processes are killed.